# does NuoDB ensures to get latest/updated data in all read operation?

Tags: mysql, database, database-replication, sharding, nuodb

I want to install NuoDB in a cloud (multiple amazon ec2 instances). before that I need to know one things:

1. does NuoDB ensures data consistency?
2. i am not a DB expert so you can treat this part as a separate point of this question or explanation of my previous point(#1) of my question:

if NuoDB is installed in a cloud that means read/write operation from application server can go to different db server. so if write goes to one server and next read goes to another server, then does NuoDB ensure that next read always get the latest/updated data that has been written in different server? I am asking this questions because you know if write goes to one server and next read goes to another server and by this if write haven’t propagated to all other servers yet because of some propagation latency then how NuoDB ensure to get latest/updated data.

or may be i didn't understand the NuoDB architecture around this matter. i found in their website that they highlighted the high availability but i don't understand if they ensure the data consistency or get latest data in all read all time or not.
so please some explain this matter.

Answer (score 1):

NuoDB is ACID compliant.

You have control via NuoDB Isolation Level settings. See these pages for more information:

- Documentation: Transactions and Isolation Levels: http://doc.nuodb.com/display/doc/Transactions+and+Isolation+Levels
- Blog Post: Isolation Levels in Terms of MVCC: http://dev.nuodb.com/techblog/isolation-levels-terms-mvcc
- NuoDB technical white paper and other technical material here: http://www.nuodb.com/resources/documents

Hope this helps. I'd be happy to answer any follow-up questions.

Steve Cellini - NuoDB product manager

Comment: if different user of my application always work with different rows of a table(possibility of concurrent insert/update in same table but by different user or different row, i mean less possibility of concurrent insert/update by same user or same row) and this table is insert/update heavy. from your given link i found READ_COMMITTED isolation level return most recent data. can you please give me suggestions that in my case will it be safe to use READ_COMMITTED isolation level? does it matter read or write goes to different db server to get most recent data?